# Why my iPhone cannot send the data to BLE?

Tags: swift, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to understand the code from this page:

https://learn.adafruit.com/crack-the-code/overview

But the problem is whenever I try to send anything from my phone to the BLE, it gives the following error:
"Error discovering services: error"
The portion of code responsible for finding the mistake(as I think) is written below:

```
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didWriteValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
    guard error == nil else {
        print("Error discovering services: error")
        return
    }
    print("Message sent")
}
```

I have read a lot of articles on that topic, but I could not find the solution to this problem.

Comment: Instead of doing `print("Error discovering services: error")`, do `print("Error discovering services: error: \(error)")` it's meaningful if you don't read the error, and tell us what's the output. Also, you print "discovering services", but it should be "error in writing" instead.

Comment: That is a good advice. The following statement emerges: "Error discovering services: error: Optional(Error Domain=CBATTErrorDomain Code=3 "Writing is not permitted." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Writing is not permitted.}) " Could you help me with that?

Comment: "Writing is not permitted". When you discovered the characteristic in question, what's its properties (`characteristic.properties`)? Cf. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcharacteristicproperties?language=objc There are properties that can only be read, etc. What about yours?

Comment: The app contains a text field whose text must be sent when a user presses the button. The value of writing here is the text inside the field. Why cannot it be read nad permitted?

Comment: Because some characteristics aren't writable. Usually, the battery level for instance. If the developer of the device want properties to be unchanged or unchanged by others (like battery, that's not your business, it's the device one)., it seems fair, no? Since you seem to use a device that you can develop on, allow the writability on that characteristic if needed.

Comment: Could you tell me how?

Comment: By looking on the Arduino part, but that's then not an iOS question, it's another one, and I don't have knowledge in Arduino. The iOS part response is: "If the characteristic property doesn't contains `CBCharacteristicProperties.write ` or `CBCharacteristicProperties.writeWithoutResponse`, you shouldn't be able to write on it by design.